# I couldn't give string as input from my input file(input.txt) to c++ program in vscode

Tags: c++, string, c++14

I am a newbie to competitive programming and I recently started into it. I started learning **C++** for **competitive programming**. From all the resources I have read I understood that we need to have some backend functions ready for us to be **fast** in competitions. So, I have prepared all of it and I have read somewhere that we can take input from file and write output to file rather than using terminal to give inputs. this I have done using **freopen()** and I ran into an issue.

The issue is that I couldn't read string input from the file(**input.txt**) or write to the output file(**output.txt**) in C++. but the reading of integers, characters, floating point numbers, everything is fine but there is only problem with the string input. I could even input strings using character arrays it works well. But sometimes using character array is not better for the program. So , if anyone could help  with that to me I would appreciate it. one more thing is that when we try to take string input the programs executes but nothing happens.

here are my codes and input and outputs
**ps:**input refers to data in input.txt at the time of execution and output refers to data in output.txt after execution

C++ version in my PC - C++14(Mingw compiler)

````
```this first code is where problem exists```
#include<iostream>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
  freopen("input.txt","r",stdin); 
  freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
  #endif
  string a;
  cin>>a;  
// here I even tried getline(cin,a) but it also doesn't work as program executes 
// but nothing will be written to output 
  cout<<a<<"\n";
  return 0;
}

input - abcdef
output- (BLANK)

----------

#include<iostream>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
  freopen("input.txt","r",stdin); 
  freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
  #endif
  int a;
  cin>>a;
  cout<<a;
  return 0;
}

input - 9
output- 9

----------

#include<iostream>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
  freopen("input.txt","r",stdin); 
  freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
  #endif
  char a[100];
  cin>>a;
  cout<<a<<"\n";
  return 0;
}

input - abcdefg
output - abcdefg

----------

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
  freopen("input.txt","r",stdin); 
  freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
  #endif
  string a="abcdef";
  cout<<a<<"\n";
  return 0;
}
input - (BLANK)
output - (BLANK)
````

Comment: I'm confused, you claim to use `freopen()` in order to run faster, but your code explicitly only uses it when not being judged. Why bother?

Comment: I have compiled the first code under MinGW included with MSYS2:
g++.exe (Rev9, Built by MSYS2 project) 10.2.0

I cannot reproduce the issue you are having. I see "abcdef" output in the output.txt file.

Comment: I always wonder about the `freopen` shuffle. Why not write functions that use generic `istream` and pass to these functions `cin` or an `ifstream` depending on need without having to screw around?

Comment: One of the best ways to write fast coed is to know how the language, the compiler and its libraries, and the hardware work. If you don't you're just cutting and pasting stuff that you heard about like a [cargo cultist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). Kudos for trying to dig a little deeper, svmk.

Comment: Suggestion: step through the program with whatever debugging tool came with your development environment and make sure `cin>>a;` really did read what you wanted it to.

Comment: Another suggestion: You won't want to do this during the competition because it'll slow things down, but when you're trying to figure out why things don't work the best place to start is by always checking the return code. Either `freopen` may have failed. You didn't look. `cin>>a;` may have failed. You didn't look. `cout<<a;` may have failed. You didn't looks. As a result, you know next to nothing about what's really going on in your program and everything will come as a surprise. In production code if you can test for failure and you don't, you're a sucker.

Comment: thank you @user4581301 for your suggestion I will look into it

Comment: @CooperHarasyn that's the issue I am trying to understand why it is not working only for me because I have seen many people use this and their code works perfect. I don't know why it is not working for me. But it works perfect when we give input through terminal and doesn't work only if we give input from input.txt file or make it write output to output.txt

Comment: @Frank as I have mentioned I am a newbie here and sorry if I have given the meaning wrong freopen() doesn't make it run faster but it does help me run faster in my pc by taking all inputs from one place and giving all output to one place without making a mess in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

At first, I wanted to tell everybody that I am not pretty sure about my answer, I am new to Stackoverflow and do not have enough reputation that's why I couldn't write comments. Answering the question is the only way that I can share my opinion or research about this question. So, please consider me as a newbie and give me your suggestion so that I can improve myself. Thank You.

Let's come to my opinion:

1. I saw you are using cin and cout in your code without adding (std::) in front of them and neither you use "using namespace std". So my question is that how could run your program without getting an error.
2. I just copy your code and try to run in my computer. And I find out that your code worked perfectly in every cases, weather I input int or string. it just worked fine. But I find out a cause where it didn't work maybe this is the problem your facing. And that is when you edit your output.txt file and you didn't save that file. Then you get nothing in your output.txt file, weather you take int or string as an input. So make sure you saved all three file and then run the main program.

That's all I got. Please let me know, my answer is helpful or Not?

Comment: Hi @Alamin_Mir, Sorry to say that I forgot to write the "using namespace std" line.
and thanks for trying to answer the question, I have tried doing that but still I couldn't read string from the file or I could write an output file